# R: Return values in a columns when the value in another column becomes negative for the first time

Tags: r, dataframe

For each ID, I want to return the value in the 'distance' column  where the value becomes negative for the first time. If the value does not become negative at all, return the value 99 (or some other random number) for that ID. A sample data frame is given below.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1, 4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4),rep(4,4),rep(5,4)),distance=rep(1:4,5), value=c(1,4,3,-1,2,1,-4,1,3,2,-1,1,-4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5))

> df
   ID distance value
1   1        1     1
2   1        2     4
3   1        3     3
4   1        4    -1
5   2        1     2
6   2        2     1
7   2        3    -4
8   2        4     1
9   3        1     3
10  3        2     2
11  3        3    -1
12  3        4     1
13  4        1    -4
14  4        2     3
15  4        3     2
16  4        4     1
17  5        1     2
18  5        2     3
19  5        3     4
20  5        4     5
```

The desired output is as follows

```
> df2
  ID first_negative_distance
1  1                       4
2  2                       3
3  3                       3
4  4                       1
5  5                      99
```

I tried but couldn't figure out how to do it through dplyr. Any help would be much appreciated. The actual data I'm working on has thousands of ID's with 30 different distance levels for each. Bear in mind that for any ID, there could be multiple instances of negative values. I just need the first one.

Edit:
Tried the solution proposed by AntonoisK.

```
> df%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise(first_neg_dist=first(distance[value<0]))
  first_neg_dist
1              4
```

This is the result I am getting. Does not match what Antonois got. Not sure why.

Comment: Do you really want `99` if no negative values exist? Is there a chance that `99` could be an actual value?

Comment: I am fine with NA as well actually. I was just using 99 as a random value that doesn't exist in my data. But I see the sense of using NA. It would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(first_neg_dist = first(distance[value < 0]))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#      ID first_neg_dist
#   <dbl>          <int>
# 1     1              4
# 2     2              3
# 3     3              3
# 4     4              1
# 5     5             NA
```

If you really prefer `99` instead of `NA` you can use

`summarise(first_neg_dist = coalesce(first(distance[value < 0]), 99L))`

instead.

Comment: >I tried this. It just returns the distance value for the first ID and not the others.  df%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise(first_neg_dist=first(distance[value<0]))
  first_neg_dist
1              4

Comment: Can you start a new R session and run it again? If you still have a problem you might need to check what packages and versions you use.